# Trouble with same cookies on subdomain and top domain

Tags: cookies

So, we've got two domains like this subsubdomain.subdomain.domain.com and subdomain.domain.com

We need to use separate social apps for these domains, 2 cookies are set, 1 for each domain. The have equal names so lower domain has access to both cookies.

The problem is that instead of taking its cookie, lower domain takes cookie from upper one.

I thought browser supposed to choose cookie with most specific domain for current but somehow it doesn't. Is there a way to handle such situations?